# WFS layer has no features in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, features

I have a layer with many features and when I add it to a map as WMS layer it works.
But if I add the layer as WFS it seems there are no features.

The code I use to load WFS layer is:

          `var layerName = '...';
          var workspace = '...';
          var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('questolayer', {
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                version: "1.1.0",
                url: "/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: layerName,
                featureNS: workspace,
                srsName: "EPSG:4326"
            })
          });
          vectorLayer.events.on({
            'loadend': function(event) {
                console.warn('00 features: ', vectorLayer.features);
            }
          });
          openlayersmap.addLayer(vectorLayer);`

If I check the response with Firebug I can see an XML with gml:featureMembers tags and many features into of it.
But the warn message '00 features' in the log contains an empty vector.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! It was because the workspace was in uppercase in GeoServer.
I convert to lowercase when I set the parameter in the protocol object and now it works.
I don't know if this is a bug.